# PDFBOX.net PDDocument Object into a database / serialization

Tags: .net, pdf, serialization, pdfbox

I hope some can shed some light on this. It looks like I need to recompile PDFBOX with the [SERIALIZE] option. But I have no idea how to.

What I am trying to do is store PDDocument doc object inside a database.

ERROR: Type 'org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument' in Assembly 'PDFBox, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.

```
    PDDocument doc = (PDDocument)documents.get(d);

    string str = ConvertForWrite(doc);

    /// Convert any object into a string which can be store in a database
    public  string ConvertForWrite(object obj)
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, obj);
        string str = System.Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
        return str;
    }
```

Thank you,
Gavin

Comment: Do you really need the serialized document object? Why not generate the PDF and store thtat in the database?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt PDFBox is easy to transform into a fully serializable library.

It won't suffice to simply add some option: While many of its classes are simple enough, others reference temporary files ("scratch files") carrying their actual contents. Custom serialization code, therefore, would be necessary in those classes.

The most natural way to serialize the data represented by a `PDDocument` instance and de-serialize it again would be to... *save it as PDF document and read that document into a `PDDocument` instance!* Using memory streams this does not require actual file system files.

Thus, you might want to create a wrapper class for `PDDocument` using [Custom Serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) techniques  which (de-)serialize by saving to / reading from a PDF document.